# How can I peek into the stack using inline assembly?

Tags: solidity, assembly

I am specifically interested in calling a function whose return-type is unknown to me.

More precisely:

- The contract which owns the function has had several versions over time
- My contract may call this function on any of the instances deployed to the network
- The function's return-type is `(uint256)` some cases and `(uint256, uint256)` in other cases

I've figured that I can call the function without storing its returned-value, so compilation by itself will not be a problem. Then, assuming that the actual values are still on the stack (is this assumption possibly wrong, due to compiler optimization or other reasons?), I can read the two topmost slots in the stack and continue as planned from that point.

Alternatively, I thought I could declare an interface of the contract in doubt, with the function in doubt returning `(uint256, uint256)`, and then use that interface in order to call the function.

However, I tried it, and the function which returns a single `uint256` has reverted:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract NotMyContract1 {
    uint256 a = 1;
    function func() external view returns (uint256) {
        return a;
    }
}

contract NotMyContract2 {
    uint256 a = 1;
    uint256 b = 2;
    function func() external view returns (uint256, uint256) {
        return (a, b);
    }
}

interface INotMyContract {
    function func() external view returns (uint256, uint256);
}

contract MyContract {
    INotMyContract private notMyContract;
    constructor(INotMyContract _notMyContract) public {
        notMyContract = _notMyContract;
    }
    function test() public view returns (uint256, uint256) {
        return notMyContract.func();
    }
}

contract("MyContract", function(accounts) {
    it("", async function() {
        await test("1");
        await test("2");
    });
    async function test(id) {
        const notMyContract = await artifacts.require("NotMyContract" + id).new();
        const myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContract").new(notMyContract.address);
        try {
            const [a, b] = await myContract.test();
            console.log(id, a.toString(), b.toString());
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(id, error.message);
        }
    }
});
```

So I would be happy to hear any idea on how to do this in assembly, as well as any alternative suggestions.

The [assembly operations](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/assembly.html) which I had in mind are `dup1 … dup16` and `swap1 … swap16`.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand the question correctly, but what you are trying to do is to call a function of a deployed contract to get the returned value? Do you have knowledge about the function (signature)?

Comment: @alberto: Yes, of course, everything but the type of the returned value (which is not part of the signature by definition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have a much easier time of this if you can use a recent version of Solidity. Starting with 0.5.x, you can get back the return value as a byte array and then decode it yourself depending on its length.

Here's some code that handles both return values (a single `uint256` or a pair of them) and returns a `0` as the second value if it wasn't returned from the external contract:

```
function test() public view returns (uint256, uint256) {
    (bool success, bytes memory returnValue) = address(notMyContract).staticcall(
        abi.encodeWithSelector(notMyContract.func.selector));

    require(success, "Call failed.");

    if (returnValue.length > 32) {
        return abi.decode(returnValue, (uint256, uint256));
    }
    else {
        uint256 a = abi.decode(returnValue, (uint256));
        return (a, 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's a Solidity 0.4.x version that uses assembly to read the return data:

```
function test() public view returns (uint256, uint256) {
    bool success = address(notMyContract).call(abi.encodeWithSelector(notMyContract.func.selector));
    require(success);
    uint256[2] memory ret;
    assembly {
        let size := returndatasize
        if gt(size, 64) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
        returndatacopy(ret, 0, size)
    }
    return (ret[0], ret[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What you wrote (the first two lines) looks very similar to a valid assembly for solc v0.4.x (which I have actually just tried, by the way, and seems to work, though it is not as clean as your code). I am unable to switch to 0.5.x at this point, because it would imply changing the entire system (contracts and truffle tests).

Comment: You can do it in 0.4.x too, but you'll need to write assembly to copy the return data. (The values are _not_ on the stack, but the return data is available from assembly.)

Comment: I added a 0.4.x version in an edit.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a warning on `call` here, since it is not `staticcall`? How would you do the whole thing in assembly then? Thank you very much by the way.

Comment: Yes, there should be a warning about doing a `call` from a `view` function. I would just ignore the warning. The other answer has an all-assembly solution.

Comment: I'm trying to go along with assembly `staticcall` (since it is not available in Solidity 0.4.x). It works fine, but my `solidity-coverage` tests fail, I believe because this tool inserts stubs into the code, and the `staticcall` execution runs out of gas. What gas value should I pass in order to avoid this? I tried `gas`, `gaslimit`, `0` and `not(0)` (suggested in the other answer). Any idea how to ensure that it always completes successfully?

Comment: `not(0)` is generally a good choice. No idea why you'd be running out of gas, sorry.

Comment: Can you think of any vulnerability in your v0.4.x suggestion? Since `staticcall` has been added in v0.5.x in order to prevent one, as far as I understand.

Comment: Not that I can think of. It's supposed to guarantee that no state changes happen, but you're calling it in a `view` function already, so why would you care about state changes?

Comment: I've actually just realized that whoever implements `notMyContract` can actually cause quite a lot of damage here, if they implement `func` in a gas-wasting manner. I care about state-changes because my `public view` function can also be used on-chain, from a non-constant function of someone else's contract. So I care about my users' to begin with.

Comment: `staticcall` is definitely safer overall. Gas wasting seems unrelated?

Comment: What if I call `func` directly (i.e., not dynamically with its function-selector bytes)? Won't `returndatasize` hold the correct value in that case?

Comment: Well, maybe I was wrong with the "gas-wasting" description. I meant like, `func` is supposed to be constant, but they can choose to make it non-constant and do a lot of bad things.

Comment: I think not, because the Solidity emitted code will have already consumed it, but I've never tried it.

Comment: OK, well thanks anyhow, your suggestion's been very helpful!

Comment: Regarding the `No idea why you'd be running out of gas` - I've finally figured it out. The `solidity-coverage` tool adds an `event` after each line of code. In order to make it possible, it first needs to change every constant function to non-constant. Subsequently, since the function which I invoke dynamically via `staticcall` has changed from constant to non-constant, `staticcall` fails (returns 0 without invoking the function). So the test fails not because of a gas issue as I have speculated, but because the expected returned value is not on the stack after the dynamic invocation is done.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the comments, maybe you are looking for something like the following. I've changed the values to see more easily the outputs.

To test, you need to pass the address of `NotMyContract1` or `NotMyContract2` as a parameter of the `getValue()` function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract NotMyContract1 {
    uint256 a = 721;
    function func() external view returns (uint256) {
        return a;
    }
}

contract NotMyContract2 {
    uint256 a = 9;
    uint256 b = 8;
    function func() external view returns (uint256, uint256) {
        return (a, b);
    }
}

contract MyContract {

    constructor() public {}

    function getValue(address _address) public view returns (uint, uint) {
        bytes4 sig = bytes4(keccak256("func()"));
        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            mstore(ptr,sig)

            let result := staticcall(not(0), _address, ptr, 0x04, ptr, 0x20)

            let size := returndatasize
            returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

            switch result case 0 { revert(0, 0) }
            default {
                if lt(size,64) { return (ptr, 0x40) }
                if gt(size,32) { return (ptr,size) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```